# How to add a button to the wx.MenuBar()?

Tags: python, button, wxpython, fullscreen, menubar

I have a following problem:

wx.Frame() in full screen mode loses System menu and Close and Minimize buttons. At least on Windows it does.

This is usually desirable, but, unfortunately, users of my application are going to be very stupid and it will be too much to expect them to use a menu to perform these two actions.
I have to stay full screen because I need much space and per pixel control.

So I will have to add these two buttons manually. I am planing to use bitmap buttons, but I am not sure on how to approach the problem.
As there is no caption, menu bar is on top of the frame.

So, do I inherit wx.MenuBar() and do something stupid there, or do I force the buttons over it? Would OS even let me to temper with the menu bar?

I hope that someone did something similar before so that I don't have to stumble around in a fog. Short examples are welcome. If they are cross-platform friendly, then they are more than welcome.

Comment: Menubar is specifically for menus, I think that you are looking for `wx.ToolBar`. See `wx.Frame.CreateToolBar()` https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Frame.html#wx.Frame.CreateToolBar

Comment: I somehow know this. :D 1. I do not have place for horizontal tool bar & 2. Oh, please, how will that look tell me. I need it to look as if the window has standard controls in the upper right corner.

Comment: The toolbar could be vertical! However, on Linux, the System menu and Close and Minimize buttons, do NOT disappear in full screen mode, so I am unable to replicate your environment, as I refuse to put "windows" on my machine.

Comment: Very clever of you. I however do have no options so I am stuck with Mac, Linux and Windows multiboot. Always switching OSes can  be damn confusing, believe me. You start using wrong commands on wrong OS and wonder, oh, why doesn't this work now! And then you realize it's the wrong OS and feel like a fool. And Windows are, as always, least helpful and most buggy. I think that frame style wx.NO_CAPTION should help on platforms that do not lose the caption by default. Can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import wx

class NoCaptionFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        no_caption = wx.RESIZE_BORDER
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="No Caption", style=no_caption)
        toolbar = self.CreateToolBar(style=wx.TB_VERTICAL)
        quittool1 = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Quit', wx.Bitmap('exit.png'))
        quittool2 = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Quit', wx.Bitmap('exit.png'))
        quittool3 = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Quit', wx.Bitmap('exit.png'))
        toolbar.Realize()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        first.Append(1,"New Window","This is a new window")
        first.Append(2,"Open...","Open A New Window")
        menubar.Append(first,"File")
        menubar.Append(second,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnQuit, quittool1)
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = NoCaptionFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Yeah, but you do not have menu bar here. Only a toolbar. Now, if you do have one, then things start to get nasty. For example, I just realized that menu bar is not considered as within a frame. The coordinate system doesn't include it, so no hope of just pushing something over it. The toolbar, regardless its orientation, is below the menu bar level.

Comment: Added a menubar and at least under Linux it looks fine. So either Windows is doing something completely different, I'm not understanding your problem or you haven't explained your problem sufficiently. Irrespective of how constrained you are for space, a control is going to eat space somewhere.